# Repeating a function on a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, tiff

I am trying to make the image shape of two .tif images match.

My approach is that I am adding blank slices at the bottom of the smaller image until their Z axis stack number match(assuming that X and Y of both images have the shape). I first turn the image into numpy array and then use np.concatenate to add an array with zeros to end of the array.

My code looks like this:

```
    x = 0
    difference = model.shape[1] - image.shape[1]

    # This line takes the difference between the larger image's Z stack 
    # slice number with the smaller image and get the difference between
    # their z stack slice number.

    while x <= difference: 
        new_np_array = np.concatenate((the_image_np_array, zeros_np_array), axis=0)
        x += 1
```

However, this wouldn't work since the program is basically defining the same variable three times. My question is, how do I repeat the function (np.concatenate) on the same array for X amount of times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly the question, you must assign the concatenation result to the array itself.

```
  while x <= difference: 
        the_image_np_array = np.concatenate((the_image_np_array, zeros_np_array), axis=0)
        x += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you're trying to accomplish but have you considered turning the images into PIL Images and using the Image.resize function?

[PIL Image docs](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html)

Comment: I would consider adding the relevant content from the link to the body of your post, or consider posting this as a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's more efficient to append to a list, and do one concatenate at the end.  And easier to get right

```
alist = []
while x <= difference: 
    alist.append(zeros_np_array)
    x += 1
arr = np.array(alist)
# arr = np.vstack(alist) # alternative
```